# Slow download speed deluge/tranmission

Tags: deluge

I switched to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS about a month ago from Windows 8.1 and everything has been running smoothly.

I decided to try downloading a magnet link today, and the download speed is less than 5kb/s despite speed test showing 15mb/s. I have no issues downloading quickly or streaming live feed from my browser.

Is there a reason that Deluge and Transmission would be downloading so slowly?

The magnet link I am downloading has over 7000 seeders with I had no issues downloading the same magnet link at full speed on a Windows 7 unit.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the upload speed to prevent the outgoing buffers in your network from filling up. With unlimited upload speed these buffers quickly fill introducing a network lag of up to several seconds in the outgoing direction. Since this lag also effects TCP control packets, it affects with your download speed as well. You want to limit your rate to just below the maximum throughput of your network so that the buffers don't fill.